# Do not show new mail notifications in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, notifications

I don't want Outlook to pop up anything to let me know when a new email has arrived. In the past there used to be an option to turn this off. Where do I find this options in Outlook 2010?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

go to
- File tab
- Options
- Click on Mail
- Scroll down to Message arrival
- Then uncheck Display a Desktop Alert and click OK
[image]

Comment: Of course, it's right where it should be - somehow I missed it, though. Thanks!